# Get 'border-width' with jQuery when 'border-style' is 'none'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, border

I need help solving this simple problem. I am trying to get the border width of an element but jQuery is always retrieving '0px', is there a way to get the 'border-width'?

```js
$('div').css({
  'border-width': '6px',
  'border-style': 'solid'
});

$('div').css({
  'color': 'rgb(207, 38, 38)'
});

$('div').css({
  'border-style': 'none'
});

console.log($('div').css('borderWidth')); //Here is the problem I need the value to be '6px'
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>element</div>
```

[Working DEMO](http://codepen.io/igcorreia/pen/XpepVY?editors=1111)

**EDIT:**

I am using google chrome, can it be a browser bug?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 2:**
I need **the jQuery solution** and not VanillaJS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it without jQuery.

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

console.log(element.style.borderWidth);
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/umkwym05/

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I need the value to be '6px' and not '0px'

Comment: yes if you check the demo now you will see the comment: http://codepen.io/igcorreia/pen/XpepVY?editors=1111

Comment: @IgnacioCorreia try `console.log($('div')[0].style.borderWidth);` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Lf92tnu5/)

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery when you can do it with plain JS?

Comment: @Fif it you are using a library/framework, you should use it. Mixing ways between Pure JS and lib will make your code little confusing

Comment: Beacuase I need to know if this is a jquery bug or if it is just me that does not know how to use Jquery

Comment: @Fif please read my comment properly. I said, you should keep your approach consistent.

Comment: @Ignacio Correia
I don't think it is problem with jQuery. jQuery returns style using this function https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle
and if you use it by yourself, you can see it returns "0px".
https://jsfiddle.net/umkwym05/2/

Comment: You can do this https://jsfiddle.net/umkwym05/4/ but honestly... it sucks. I don't know why you want so badly use jQuery.